# host multiple website with nginx

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, nginx, nginx-location

I have Ubuntu server 16.04 server with nginx install (nginx/1.10.3)

I have only one DNS name `energy.mysite.local` Which I need to use for multiple websites.

I have 2 Directories in which I have placed website content

```
  1) /var/www/website/
  2) /var/www/web-site/
```

my sites-available & sites-enabled folders content 2 files
`website & web-site`

Content for `website`

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location /website/ {
             alias /var/www/website/;
             gzip_static on;
             expires max;
             add_header Cache-Control public;
             autoindex off;
    }

    server_name energy.mysite.local/website;

    location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Content for `web-site`

```
server {

    listen 443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location /web-site/ {
             alias /var/www/web-site/;
             gzip_static on;
             expires max;
             add_header Cache-Control public;
             autoindex off;
    }

    server_name energy.mysite.local/web-site;

    location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

So that I can able use below website

`https://energy.mysite.local/website/1.0.1/src/abc.js`

`https://energy.mysite.local/web-site/2.0.1/src/abc.js`

At present `https://energy.mysite.local/web-site/2.0.1/src/abc.js` is working fine.

However `https://energy.mysite.local/website/1.0.1/src/abc.js` is giving me `404` page

Any way to get it done?

Comment: Those are subdirectories of the same domain and need to be placed inside the same `server` block. The value for `server_name` must only include the domain name part.

Comment: I tried that, but it isn't working, Could you show how exact code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, the two locations appear to share the same root, in which case the separate [`location` blocks](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [`alias` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) may not be necessary.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name energy.mysite.local;

    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    root /var/www;

    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```